# Removing a subarraylist from mainarraylist in android

Tags: android

I'm using Android 2.3.3. I have a `mainArrayList<String>`, and a `subArrayList<String>` which has content that is part of `mainArrayList<String>`. I wish to remove this `subArrayList<String>` from the `mainArrayList<String>`.

How do I do it?

I tried using `alMainArrayList.remove(alSubArrayList)`. But it doesn't work. Can someone help me?

Ex:

```
alMainArrayList<String> = [1,+,(,2,*,(,3,+,4,),),)]
alSubArrayList<String> = [(,3,+,4,)]
```

For more information, I am developing a calculator app, where in i have the given expression in a `ArrayList<String> alMainArrayList`. After performing the evaluation of a sub expression, I wish to remove it from the alMainArrayList and then insert the result into it at the specified index. The code complies.

The problem is, the subexpression, which i have in alSubArrayList doesn't get deleted, when i use `alMainArrayList.remove(alSubArrayList)` or even `alMainArrayList.removeAll(alSubArrayList)`.

It's a loop, and so the result gets added at the specified index (without first deleting the subArrayList) and the loop enters into infinite loop.

To provide the code snippet, it's a bit hard. They are bits of pieces here and there. So, if someone understood what i wanted to say, please help me.

Comment: What doesn't work? What happens when you compile the code yo gave?

Comment: There is no error. But when i run the app, the alMainArrayList remains the same.

Comment: FYI, you should use correct Java syntax in your question. A short snippet of code which we can compile would be helpful. See [this article](http://www.sscce.org) for some tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a method subList() for the ArrayList.

Here is the information as per the help, when you place it on the method.

subList() :::: for an ArrayList

Returns a part of consecutive elements of this list as a view. The returned view will be of zero length if start equals end. Any change that occurs in the returned subList will be reflected to the original list, and vice-versa. All the supported optional operations by the original list will also be supported by this subList.

This method can be used as a handy method to do some operations on a sub range of the original list, for example list.subList(from, to).clear();

If the original list is modified in other ways than through the returned subList, the behavior of the returned subList becomes undefined.

The returned subList is a subclass of AbstractList. The subclass stores offset, size of itself, and modCount of the original list. If the original list implements RandomAccess interface, the returned subList also implements RandomAccess interface.

The subList's set(int, Object), get(int), add(int, Object), remove(int), addAll(int, Collection) and removeRange(int, int) methods first check the bounds, adjust offsets and then call the corresponding methods of the original AbstractList. addAll(Collection c) method of the returned subList calls the original addAll(offset + size, c).

The listIterator(int) method of the subList wraps the original list iterator. The iterator() method of the subList invokes the original listIterator() method, and the size() method merely returns the size of the subList.

All methods will throw a ConcurrentModificationException if the modCount of the original list is not equal to the expected value.

Parameters
start  start index of the subList (inclusive). 
end  end index of the subList, (exclusive).

Returns
a subList view of this list starting from start (inclusive), and ending with end (exclusive)
Throws
IndexOutOfBoundsException  if (start < 0 || end > size()) 
IllegalArgumentException  if (start > end)

Comment: +1 for this info. Moreover, don't ever use subList as a content of `ListAdapter` if you're going to modify an amount of elements in your `ListView` without hard consideration - ConcurrentModificationExceptions are guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

The code you gave tells Java to remove a reference to a List from `alMainArrayList`. This shouldn't even compile if `alMainArrayList` is really declared as `List<String>` or `ArrayList<String`. Obviously it won't change the `List` because it doesn't contain references to `List`s.

With that said, you should check out [removeAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29.). I believe this will do what you want.

Comment: I cannot add the code snippet because it's part of different functions. I have edited the question, can you check it again..

Comment: @VamsiChalla Did you try my suggestion? And did you read the article that I linked?

Comment: @VamsiChalla When I ask questions here, I find that it helps to write a fresh program from scratch which recreates the problem. This has at least two benefits: 1) my mind becomes focused on the real problem so that I can explain it to others more easily and 2) sometimes I figure out the solution on my own.

Comment: Ok.. I tried your suggestion removeAll(). It didnt work. I will read the doc and will get back to you.

Comment: @VamsiChalla I suggest that you write a small (new) program which recreates the exact problem which you have encountered. Post it here and we can help from there.